# Force excel workbook to avoid auto recalculation upon opening it on other PC until changes are made

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calculation

I have the following situation:

- I created a rather gigantic excel workbook with a bunch of excel worksheets and a lot of cross-dependencies between worksheets in it and a lot of heavy formulas. I saved this file. When I open it on my laptop it doesn't try to automatically recalculate content since Excel realizes that data didn't change. When I make changes in data recalculation is fast since changes in data will be localized and won't affect the whole workbook making it possible to make adjustments to workbook without spending hours to wait for calculation completion.
- When I give a copy of this workbook to anyone else and they open it on their PC it seems that Excel decides (not sure why - wasn't able to find any answer) to recalculate entire workbook. Probably that's a default behavior when excel file is opened on different PC.
- Since workbook is huge recalculation of everything in it will take forever

Is there any way to force excel to assume that whichever values are populated in the cells right now are 'correct' (that all cells don't require recalculation) but still preserve the Automatic recalculation behavior when user changes something in the data? Basically, we need to remove '[dirty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#dependence-dirty-cells-and-recalculated-cells)' status from all cells in the workbook when it is opened on new PC.

Comment: cHECK https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/276520-turn-off-auto-calculation-when-launching-xls-file.html

Comment: And also check https://superuser.com/questions/184276/how-to-open-excel-without-refreshing-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not answer Your question, but i may provide a solution for Your problem: 
Have You tried to enter

```
Application.Calculation= xlCalculationManual
Application.CalculateBeforeSave=False
```

into the direct-window (Ctrl+G while in developers mode)?
You can reactivate the automatic calculation modes later, for example with an "Workbook_Change" -Event, or manually in the direct-window.
I have a few other possible "Work-arounds" in mind, please let me know, if you are interested. This might also help to understand Excels calculations: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecrets.htm

Comment: It has nothing to do with the issue at hand. This action will just switch excel to Manual calculation mode and disable calculate before save. If user makes updates to any part of workbook - whole workbook will be recalculate. What I need is a way to remove the 'dirty' status from all cells in the workbook. I can do it with VBA but I was looking for a UI based answer.